# How to call events or methods like onTextChanged of EditText in Fabric native components react native

Tags: android, react-native, kotlin, react-native-native-module

I am working on fabric native component and i need to access some methods like,

```
getText()
onChangedText()
onClick()
isEnabled()
```

how to call these types of methods in fabric native component in android as of now i am following this doc https://reactnative.dev/docs/next/the-new-architecture/pillars-fabric-components.